# Dúvidas de utilização de delegates

Tags: c#, delegate

Ainda não consegui absorver por completo o uso dos delegates, em que momento realmente eu devo usar um delegate e o porque da sua construção. Então faço a seguinte pergunta à comunidade. O que é realmente um delegate? Essa é a pergunta e ela exige uma única resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Delegate* é um tipo do C# (e outras linguagens .Net) que representa uma determinada assinatura de método (define o tipo dos parâmetros e o retorno do método).

Podemos declarar um *delegate* do mesmo jeito que declaramos uma classe (com sintaxe bem diferente, claro, mas com conceito semelhante).

Seguindo com a analogia, uma variável do tipo de uma certa classe vai referenciar um objeto daquele tipo, enquanto uma variável do tipo de um certo delegate vai referenciar um método com aquela assinatura.

> *Delegates* facilitam a implementação ou oferecem uma opção de implementação de alguns *design patterns* como **Delegation**, **Inversion of control** e **Observer**.

Você pode conseguir os mesmos resultados usando **interfaces** em vez de *delegates*.

Algumas vantagens de usar *delegates* é precisar de menos código e eventualmente ter um código mais expressivo.

Por exemplo, se um objeto vai delegar apenas a execução de um único método a outro objeto e não terá nenhuma outra interação com aquele outro objeto além de disparar este único método, usar interface pode ser um exagero já que ela tem a capacidade de definir um objeto complexo com vários membros e o objeto delegador só está interessado em um único membro. Neste caso *delegate* pode ser mais indicado do que *interface*.

Se você já desenvolveu interface gráfica desktop em C# (**Windows Forms**) você está bastante familiarizado com o uso de delegates: o gerador de código do editor de formulários utiliza **delegates** e **events** (um outro facilitador) para implementar o pattern **observer**. É assim que os controles notificam o teu código quando um usuário clica em um botão, por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Um delegate é um tipo de referência que pode ser usado para encapsular um método nomeada ou anônimo. Delegates são semelhantes aos ponteiros de função em C++; entretanto, delegates são fortemente tipados e seguros. Para aplicativos de delegados.

Recomendo a leitura deste artigo para uma explicação bem detalhada e com exemplos:

http://www.macoratti.net/11/05/c_dlg1.htm

Aqui outro artigo:

http://www.frameworksystem.com/blog/o-que-sao-delegates-c-net1/